# ajax request not taking place when form is submitted

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to use Ajax for a form but it seems not to be working. I'm not sure if it's because the file is php but being shown as a javascript file, or something along those lines but I would like to get this fixed. Thanks in advance.

login/index.php

```
<!doctype html>
<html>

    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

        <title><?php echo SERVER_NAME; ?> | <?php echo $this->title ?></title>

        <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo URL; ?>/public/css/bootstrap.min.css"></link>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo URL; ?>/public/css/css.login.php" />

        <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo URL; ?>/public/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo URL; ?>/public/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>

        <div id="login" class="container">
            <div class="module">
                <div class="module-header">
                    <h4>Login</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="module-body module-padding">
                    <form class="form" method="post" action="<?php echo URL;?>/actions/login.php">
                        <input type="text" name="login-username" placeholder="Username">
                        <br />
                        <input type="password" name="login-password" placeholder="Password">
                        <br />
                        <input type="submit" name="submit" placeholder="Login" class="pull-right">
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="msg">

            </div>
        </div>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo URL; ?>/public/js/user-login.php"></script>

    </body>
</html>
```

user-login.php (acts as js)

```
<?php

    header('Content-Type: application/javascript');

    require "../../Application/Configuration/config.php";

?>

$(window).load(function() {
    $('.form').submit(function(event) {
        var formData = {
            'login-username': $('input[name=login-username]').val(),
            'login-password': $('input[name=login-password]').val()
        };

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "<?php echo URL; ?>/actions/login.php",
            data: formData,
            success: function (json_data) {
                var data_array = $.parseJSON(json_data);
                if (data_array['error'] == false) {
                    $('.msg').css('display', 'block');
                    $('.msg').addClass('msg-success');
                    $('.msg p').html(data_array['text']);
                    $('.msg').fadeOut(4000);
                    var delay = 4000;
                    setTimeout(function() {
                        window.location.replace("../index.php");
                    }, delay);
                } else {
                    $('.msg').css('display', 'block');
                    $('.msg').addClass('msg-failure');
                    $('.msg p').html(data_array['text']);
                    $('.msg').fadeOut(4000);
                }
            },
            fail: function () {
                alert("failed to send");
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: better you get the `action` attribute of your form as a `url`

Comment: When you say it doesn't work, does it at least get unemployment benefits? Maybe you should explain what exactly doesn't work, and what you've done to fix it.

Comment: Ahh sorry @adeneo. Mind is boggled and I didn't even realize I didn't explain it. When I submit the form it just goes to the page actions/login.php and it's all white and displays the outputted json text instead of returning it into ajax to be displayed on the same page as submitted.

Comment: I don't see where you are preventing the default form action. I see the `event` in `{('.form').submit(function(event) {`, but I don't see a `event.PreventDefault();`. So right now your form is posting traditionally, and not via Ajax

Comment: As noted above here, there's nothing stopping the form from submitting, so the behaviour you're seeing is what is expected from the posted code. You have to add `.preventDefault()`

Comment: Question: What do you want? To submit your form with reloading the page or without? Because using AJAX, you don't need to do submit form because this will reload the page, so then skip the AJAX request.

Comment: `$('.form').submit(function(event) { event.preventDefault(); ...` Anyone know of a good dupe? I am just finding really low score ones.

Comment: Thanks @Sean and adeneo.

Comment: if your ajax is expecting a JSON formatted return, then you must add `dataType: 'json'` for it to undestand what the php is sending back.